# How to display a custom view in the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to display a custom view in the action bar. I am using SherlockActionBar.
Here is my code. The custom view is never showing. What am I doing wrong?

```
View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must enable custom views first.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); // missing in your code
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
```